# Incorrect sign when evaluating of bounds of integral

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, parametric

Apparently either I've forgotten some basic rule about integrals (it has been a while since I've taken a basic calc class) or something is wrong with this problem in pearson mylab.

This was the problem:

Evaluate $\int_C\frac{x^2}{y^{4/3}}ds$ where C is the curve $x=t^2,y=t^3$ for $-3\le{t}\le-1$

The answer that it finally accepted was $\frac1{27}(85^{3/2}-13^{3/2})$

I've been wracking my brain trying to figure out why it's not $\frac1{27}(13^{3/2}-85^{3/2})$

After all, (unless I suddenly can't work out integrals, which seems unlikely given that I did a bunch of very similar problems before and after this with no problem) the antiderivative should work out to $\frac1{27}(4+9t^2)^{3/2}$ and then you just work out the values at $t=-1$ and $t=-3$ and subtract the first from the second.

Am I missing something obvious or is this problem actually just borked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your antiderivative is incorrect because you are missing a minus sign. Once you substitute the parametrization you should have
$$\int_{-3}^{-1} \sqrt{4t^2+9t^4} \ dt.$$
In order to pull the $t^2$ out of the square root, we need to make it $|t|$ (recall that the square root function by definition returns a nonnegative number, so $\sqrt{a^2}=|a|$, not just $a$). Since $t$ is negative on the interval $[-3,-1]$, $|t|=-t$ on this interval. Therefore the integral becomes:
$$\int_{-3}^{-1}-t\sqrt{4+9t^2} \ dt.$$

Comment: Nothing to say. Correct.

Comment: Ugh, I knew it was going to be something obvious. I even thought about that for other problems and said 'nah, it's fine because it's always positive.' Thanks for the answer, I'll be able to sleep tonight now.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{x^2}{y^{\frac 43}}=\frac{t^4}{t^4}=1$$

The integral is 
$$L=\int_C ds$$
it is also the length of the curve between the left point $A=(1,-1) $ for $t=-1$ and the right point  $B=(9,-27)$ for $t=-3.$

so

$$L=\int_{-1}^{-3}t\sqrt{4+9t^2}dt$$